# Two wordpress installs on same domain how to share database?

Tags: database, wordpress

I have 2 wordpress installs on one domain what I want to do is have both installs update posts as I add a post to the main install, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may be possible to have 2 front facing domains use the same database (share posts) but you will need to make the options parts different tables since they will use different themes/plugins I presume. Take a look at this page they seem to be on the right path. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/2-sites-1-db-possible?replies=15

Comment: I wouldn't advise to use an 11 year old wp forum topic as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a few problems.

First of all, wordpress saves domain names in the database. Also, in posts itself, when you add an image for example, the domain where you are on will be used in that post.

And as what you are doing is highly unusual, third party plugin builders don't take this situation into account, so any new plugin could break your setup in unexpected ways.

Another possible problem, but maybe not really one that concerns you is duplicate content. You'll get two exactly the same articles on two domains, without a [canonical url](https://yoast.com/rel-canonical/).

Basically I would advise against this. There just are too many unknowns. Maybe a better approach is to investigate how to use WP multisite in this situation, and share content between the sites ([this could do the trick](https://wordpress.org/plugins/threewp-broadcast/)), or use an alternative like [ManageWP](http://managewp.com/)